# Obtener registros de una tabla que estén entre un rango de fechas, con NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Necesito obtener los registros de una tabla que estén entre un rango de fechas, en la consulta que hice en la pgAdmin use lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE dtm_created BETWEEN '2019-11-05'
AND '2019-11-07';
```

y me funciona.
Intente obtener los registros que coincidan con la fecha actual:

```
const getAll = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getModels()
      .then(models => {
        let OrderModel = models.OrderModel

        let hoy = new Date();

        OrderModel.findAll({
          attributes: ['int_id', 'int_sequence', 'dtm_requested_date', 'str_reception_hour', 'dtm_aproved_date', 'dtm_created'],
          where: {dtm_aproved_date: hoy}          
        })
          .then(rows => resolve(rows))
          .catch(err => { throw err })

      })
      .catch(err => reject(`error.orders.models.order. ${err}`))
  })
}
```

Ahora necesito hacer lo mismo en mi codigo con NodeJs y Sequelize, pero al comparar una fecha y ejecutar, no me muestra error pero no me devuelve resultados.